# How can I serialize a `struct` with Strings using Borsh?

Tags: rust, solana

I have this `struct`:

```
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct User {
    pub name: String,
}
```

And along with it a program to simply associate it with a Solana account and set a name:

```
pub fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    let account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    let mut user_account = User::try_from_slice(&account.data.borrow())?;

    user_account.name = String::from("John Doe");
    msg!("{:?}", user_account);

    user_account.serialize(&mut &mut account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;

    Ok(())
}
```

I am running this contract on a `localhost` server. Most of this code is taken from the [Solana Labs "Hello, World!"](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld) example (with the main changes being mentioned above).

The error comes at the second-to-last line, when trying to serialize `user_account`:

```
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown 
Program 6rJVDwbQZUvpK5WKYNtYWgrSXym58DC7V7EV2YnpdEAk invoke [1]
Program log: User { name: "John Doe" }
Program 6rJVDwbQZUvpK5WKYNtYWgrSXym58DC7V7EV2YnpdEAk consumed 4839 of 1400000 compute units
Program 6rJVDwbQZUvpK5WKYNtYWgrSXym58DC7V7EV2YnpdEAk failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown
```

My goal with this program is to be able to have a `String` field in a `struct`, and have it be serialized by Borsh.

Interestingly enough, replacing `String::from("John Doe")` with `String::new()` or `String::from("")` does not yield the error, but the program succeeds in this case with the name being set to an empty string.

Comment: It's because the data doesn't have enough space to store the String ... have a look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68124332/i-notice-when-i-try-and-use-borsh-to-serialize-deserialize-ill-get-errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I notice when I try and use Borsh to serialize/deserialize I'll get errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68124332/i-notice-when-i-try-and-use-borsh-to-serialize-deserialize-ill-get-errors)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the formal specification for Borsh, it says that strings are encoded as:

```
String, string_type: "String", encoded = utf8_encoding(x) as Vec<u8>, repr(encoded.len() as u32) repr(encoded as Vec<u8>)
```

Which means that it encodes the length of the string as a `u32`, followed by the utf-8 encoded string bytes.  For the string "John Doe", you need to have 12 bytes, 4 for the length, and 8 for the contents.

If you want to do this programmatically, you either need to do `system_program::create_account` with the calculated bytes beforehand, or you can do `create_account` on-chain using a program-derived address.

More information about the Borsh specification at: https://github.com/near/borsh#specification

Comment: That actually helped to resolve my problem :)